# Why does upgrading to AGP 8.3.0-alpha06 make build fail with "No value passed for parameter 'providers'"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have upgraded my android studio version to

```
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 6
Build #AI-232.9921.47.2321.10875067, built on September 28, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.8+0-17.0.8b1000.22-10799086 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 5120M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.github.rmehri01.onenord (0.0.7)
    com.arcticicestudio.nord.jetbrains (0.13.0)
```

and the AGP to version `8.3.0-alpha06`

now my build fails on these two lines

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties

val googleApiKey: String = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("GOOGLE_API_KEY")
val googleCrashReportingApiKey: String = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("GOOGLE_CRASH_REPORTING_API_KEY")


* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 16: val googleApiKey: String = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("GOOGLE_API_KEY")
                                                            ^ No value passed for parameter 'providers'

  Line 17: val googleCrashReportingApiKey: String = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("GOOGLE_CRASH_REPORTING_API_KEY")
                                                                          ^ No value passed for parameter 'providers'

2 errors
```

Im guessing `rootDir` is `null`, however how do I resolve this issue?
What is the root cause?

I have now upgraded to Canary 7 and i get this issue when attempting to upgrade the AGP

[image]

I fixed this issue by replacing with

```
val properties = Properties().apply { load(FileInputStream(File(rootProject.rootDir, "local.properties"))) }

val googleApiKey: String = properties.getProperty("GOOGLE_API_KEY")
val googleCrashReportingApiKey: String = properties.getProperty("GOOGLE_CRASH_REPORTING_API_KEY")
```

Answer (score 7):

I fixed the problem by replacing this:

```
gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("GOOGLE_API_KEY")
```

By adding the `providers` parameter like this:

```
gradleLocalProperties(rootDir, providers).getProperty("GOOGLE_API_KEY")
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant "gradleLocalProperties(rootDir, providers)" instead of "gradleLocalProperties(rootDir, provider)"?

Answer (score 6):

Environment

```
com.android.application 8.3.0
```

Need to add `providers` field and resync your project (don't need to create this filed)

```
gradleLocalProperties(rootDir, providers).apply {
    storePassword = getProperty("storePwd")
    keyAlias = getProperty("keyAlias")
    keyPassword = getProperty("keyPwd")
}
```